# Finding min(A+B+C) when N = A*B*C is given

Tags: math, primes

I've encountered a problem like this:

> given positive integer N, find **min(A+B+C)** 
> when A,B,C are also positive
> integers and **A*B*C = N.**

I've managed to factorize N with pollard-rho algorithm. But since A, B, C are integers, it seems hard to distribute prime factors.

(for clarity, N <= 1e15)

is this problem well known? What algorithm would be best?

---

I've tried:

(greedy) Let A, B, C = 1.
iterating from largest prime factor to smallest, find minimum from A, B, C and multiply the prime factor.

This fails for N = 986387345919360 = 2^7 * 3^4 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37

Comment: I suspect this is NP-hard (in the number of prime factors).

Answer (score 1):

Self answering because I solved it;

My algorithm looks like this:

1. Sort all divisors of N by ascending order.

- it is known that N's divisor count cannot exceed 26880.

2. Iterating through the list, let A be the iterating divisor. Then B*C = N/A.

- since A is fixed, the problem reduces to a small version of itself.

3. Compute **S = sqrt(N/A)**. B and C should be close as possible to S.

- Using binary search in the sorted divisor list at step 1, let **B = lower bound of S**. If this B cannot divide S, iterate backwards until B|S.

This algorithm's time complexity is NOT O(NlogN) because finding B uses iteration, but still runs pretty well.

Comment: I suggest calculating the time complexity in function of the number of prime factors, not in function of N.

Comment: If N <= 1e50, the number of prime divisors of N cannot be more than 50.

Comment: If N <= 1e15 as in the original question, it has at most 26880 divisors (866421317361600 is the only number in that range with that number of divisors). It can have at most 49 prime divisors (2^49 and 2^48*3 are the only examples) and at most 13 distinct prime divisors (2 * 3 * ... * 41 is an example).

Comment: The run time is at most exp(k*log n/log log n) where k is log 4 + o(1).